# Can I use the WordPress visual editor in a plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am writing the settings menu for a plugin I am developing and I would like to use the custom input that WordPress uses on the dashboard for page and post content.

The idea is to let the user easily add HTML files to the plugin.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The user should be allowed to add html markup? That sounds like a huge security gap...

Comment: @arkascha Is this an issue? This is my first time writing a plugin from scratch, but I have used plenty of plugins in the past that allow users to upload content using custom HTML.

Comment: Well, you allow users to load arbitrary code into your site. That code may contain scripts that again can do more or less what they want. For example they can change about everything your site delivers, change the look, content and behavior. Many attacks along that way are well known, CSRF, sesion highjacking, malware embedding, ...

Comment: @arkascha the plugin I am designing lets the user (with the role of Editor or above) add content to a page with specific formatting, from the dashboard. Just to clarify, when i said user, i was referring to the users of the plugins admin interface, not website visitors.

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something else! You should have mentioned this in the question ;-) Indeed I coded such things myself in the past. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with wp_editor?
    wp_editor();

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor